# How can the C++ const_cast be implemented in C

Tags: c, const-cast

Let's assume a function in our C language module receives the following pointer `struct some_type const* p` as function parameter. Furthermore, we know that the `struct some_type` object pointed to by `p` cannot be in *really const* storage (for instance because `struct some_type` is *defined* in our module only, and the outside world just sees a forward declaration; our module is the only place in which pointers to real `struct some_type` objects (other than `NULL` pointers) can be created.

Now, our function would like to create a pointer-to-non-const from `p` (whithout using a brutal `(struct some_type*)p` cast). In C++ for instance, there is `const_cast<struct some_type*>(p)`. How would one implement similar functionality in C (preferably C99, possibly with GCC extensions)?

The implementation should have the following properties:

- delivers a `struct some_type*` result which compares equal to `p` if `*p` is of type `struct some_type` (possibly cv qualified)
- fails to compile if the previous condition does not hold

Usage of compiler extensions (like GCC `__typeof__`) will probably be unavoidable.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the first of your properties. If the function argument `p` is of type `X *`, then how can `*p` ever not be of type `X`?

Comment: Assuming the pointer your C function gets from C++ code was created by another function in your C module, instead of using a `struct some_type const *`, just use `void *` in C++ and simply directly assign it without casting to a `struct some_type *` when it's passed to C from C++. If the C++ code never has to dereference the pointer, using `void *` will avoid this entire problem.

Comment: Another alternative if the C++ code doesn't have to dereference the pointer is to provide only an [opaque structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) definition in your external header file.  If the external C++ code doesn't have a definition for `struct some_type`, having a `struct some_type *` value without the `const` really doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Art My function takes an `X const*` (note the pointer-to-_const_ here), so `*p`is of type `X const`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle In theory, you are right in that the `const` does not do anything (at least from the user point of view). In fact, my use case is indeed something like `typedef struct some_type const* MyHandle` in the external header file and then having the user get handles from my module and have my module operate on handles supplied by the user. However, I'd like to follow a policy of having everything `const` unless mutability is explicitly needed -- even in my module.